# RabbitMQPublisher sometimes fails to recover

Tags: rabbitmq, vert.x

I am using Vertx 4.2.1 with RabbitMQ client and I just noticed that sometimes when the rabbitMQ client loose connection and reconnect, the RabbitMQPublisher is not able to publish messages anymore. It means that my call to publisherClient.rxPublish(...) never completes and it does not throw any error.

My client settings are:

```
new RabbitMQOptions().setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true)
                    .setReconnectAttempts(0)
                    .setNetworkRecoveryInterval(1000L);
```

Are there some settings or something to prevent this situation ?

For now, I am trying to resolve the issue with the following workaround:

```
publisherClient.rxPublish(......)
                    .timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .doOnError(err -> {
                        if (err instanceof TimeoutException) {
                            LOG.warn("Publisher did not recover, so it will be restarted");
                            publisherClient.restart();
                        }
                    })
                    .retry(1L, err -> err instanceof TimeoutException)
```

As a small update on the issue:
It seems to be reproducible, if we try to publish a message while a connection to RabbitMQ is down, we won't be able to publish any message later even if the connection is recovered and everything seems to be ok. The call to publisherClient.rxPublish(......) never completes

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

How are you testing this? And how are you creating the exchange and queue that you are publishing to?

If the objects are not there when the server comes back then all messages will silently disappear.
In order to create the objects you need to use the connection established callbacks, which are not currently accessible via the Rx wrapper.

Comment: I have my backend connected to RabbitMQ, once I stop the rabbitMQ server, I send some requests to my backed which should be forwarded to a queue. Finally, I start the rabbitMQ again and once is started, I try to send again some requests but these request are never forwarded in RabbitMQ and there is no error in the console, the rxPublish is just never resolved and stay blocked. I create my queues when the rabbitMQ client connects for the first time, my queues are durable and quorum type so they survive the connection lost.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```java
publisherClient.rxPublish(......)
  .timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  .doOnError(err -> {
      if (err instanceof TimeoutException) {
          LOG.warn("Publisher did not recover, so it will be restarted");
          publisherClient.restart();
      }
  })
  .retry(1L, err -> err instanceof TimeoutException)
  .subscribe()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).